# Banach algebra with identity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

suppose that $A$ is a  Banach algebra with identity, $a, b \in A$:

‎‎a) are these correct?

$ ‎\sigma(a+b)‎‎ ‎\subseteq‎ ‎\sigma(a) ‎+‎\sigma(b)‎‎ $‎

‎‎$ ‎\sigma(ab)‎\subseteq‎‎‎ ‎\sigma(a)‎\sigma(b)‎‎ $‎

> **can you show me that abelian condition $A$ is necessary?**

b)if $ab=ba$,

$ ‎\sigma(a+b)‎‎ ‎\subseteq‎ ‎\sigma(a) ‎+‎\sigma(b)‎‎ $‎

‎‎$ ‎\sigma(ab)‎\subseteq‎‎‎ ‎\sigma(a)‎\sigma(b)‎‎ $‎

Comment: Is $A$ a real or a complex Banach algebra?

Comment: $A$ is a complex Banach algebra.

Comment: Do you know a relation between $\sigma(x)$ for $x\in A$, and the (unital) algebra homomorphisms $A \to \mathbb{C}$?